# Узнать по какой кнопке в классе кликнули

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

```
$(".delButton").click(function () {
 //Код 
 //здесь надо обратиться именной к той кнопке из всего класса по которой кликнули.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте $(this)

```js
$(".delButton").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="delButton" href="#one">Первая ссылка</a><br />
<a class="delButton" href="#two">Вторая ссылка</a><br />
<a class="delButton" href="#three">Третья ссылка</a><br />
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Коротко и просто через event.target:

```js
$('.click-button').click((event)=> {
  $('.result').html(event.target.textContent);
})
```

```css
.result {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='click-button'>Годзила</button>
<button class='click-button'>Кинг-конг</button>
<button class='click-button'>Бульбаш</button>
<div class='result'></div>
```